# Android - evaluate device performance in app/game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I just started using libgdx to develop android games and i'm currently developing a game which would adjust the quantity and/or quality of the enemies/animations/drops/etc shown in the screen, depending on how many the device supports.

Some devices may be faster and support a greater amount of enemies, but others may begin to lag and i wanted to prevent that by disabling some options of the game, without any user interaction.
But i'm facing a problem: i don't know how to evaluate the device RAM, GPU, etc. and even if i did, i don't know how many enemies i can have given the device specifications.

Is there any way to estimate how many enemies/animations/drops/etc i can have for a device?

Comment: monitor your framerate? if it drops too much, adjust settings.

Comment: it's a good and simple workaround. Thanks! But if the default is set too high the user might still notice the first framerate drop while it is adjusting. Is there any other ways?

Comment: My recommendation here is: Program first, optimize later. Do not worry about performance yet. Waste of time. Today's devices are very powerful. If you are done with your game and run into performance problems then it is time to fix the issues by finding performance leaks in your code. After that you may consider device specific adjustment options.